# How to fix gap between carpet and wall to prevent rodent?

Tags: drywall, stairs, pest-control, carpet, pest

Our condo is located in a forest/mountain area and we have suffered some rodent issues lately. We have two stories, and bedrooms are located downstairs. As I sleep at night, I often hear sound of rodents running around and scratching wood floor upstairs. The other day I think I found the gap where rodents can get into our condo. As shown in the picture, there are gaps between carpet and dry wall along the stairs, and gaps look pretty big for rodents to get in (but I am still not sure if this is the case).

If this seems like where the rodent can get into our condo, what would be a fix here? How can I block or seal this gap completely?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the management company sent a pest control specialist out to our apartment to deal with mice, he stuffed coarse steel wool or wire mesh into any little crevasses like that he could find. He claimed the mice couldn't chew through it, didn't like the feel of it. Not a great permanent solution, but maybe a good first try?

Comment: If it's a farm fix, it's probably a good one!

Answer (score 1):

Great Stuff makes a foam specifically for pest control. It's easy to apply and expands to fill cracks and voids. It's available at all home stores.

Here's a picture so you know what to look for. 
[image]

Comment: I'll add that you have to be careful with Great Stuff - read the warning labels. It has a good reputation for doing what it says, but all the hazardous chemical warnings have left me uncomfortable using it inside an inhabited space.